# Ver el contenido de un fichero binario

Tags: c++

¿Cómo se puede ver el contenido de un fichero binario en Visual Studio? Estoy utilizando C++.
¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: que es lo que has intentado, por favor

Comment: He intentado abrir un archivo con extensión .bin pero como es binario, no se puede ver el contenido de ese archivo, querría saber cómo ver el contenido de un archivo binario.

Comment: ya, pero como lo has intentado?, pon el codigo porfa

Comment: No es nada de fichero.read((char*)... ni fichero.write((const char*)..., solo quiero ver el contenido de ese archivo, como quien abre un txt con el bloc de notas.
Al igual que con linux en el terminal se pone hexdump -c nombrebinario.dat, quiero hacer lo mismo pero con Visual Studio

Comment: http://decodigo.com/c-plus-plus-leer-archivo-de-texto

Comment: Y qué crees que vas a ver en un fichero binario? Lo puedes abrir como texto en un editor de texto, pero te saldrán caracteres ilegibles.

Comment: Sí es legible, querría saber cómo hacer esto: https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/Screenshot-from-2018-12-17-00-59-07.png pero en Visual Studio.

Comment: Mira a ver si te sirve esta extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.hexeditor

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: @user152563 te lo pongo como respuesta

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Hay una extensión para VS Code de Microsoft que se llama HexEditor que te permite editar ficheros binarios viendo su representación en hexadecimal.

Sus características principales son:

- Abrir ficheros en hexadecimal
- Navegar y hacer scroll sobre ellos
- Ver los valores hexadecimales en diferentes formatos
- Edición sencilla con opción de deshacer y rehacer

En el siguiente enlace se puede descargar la extensión correspondiente.

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.hexeditor

Si se necesita ayuda para buscar e instalar extensiones, en el siguiente enlace se indican detalles de cómo hacerlo:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-using-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019

Comment: Revisar [answer] , recuerda "agregar el contexto alrededor de los enlaces".

Comment: @Jorgesys gracias por la sugerencia, he editado la respuesta para dar más contexto a los enlaces. Si hay algo más que pueda hacer para mejorar la respuesta por favor indicádmelo.